# Xcode Assistance with Coding

Tags: html, ios, xcode

I am trying to figure out how to do an extension for a html file. I'm new to coding and Xcode and trying to create an app but I have enough experience in coding to understand what goes where and why.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to add an extension to a html file; example

(index.html?lc=uk) instead of (index.html).

I've created a interface and all the other information required but I can't seem to get this part to work. The coding I'm using on the ViewController.m is;

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"354"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:request];
```

I've tried adding to the (pathForResource) @"index.html?lc=uk" but when I test the app it doesn't work and gives me an error.

Can someone give me a idea on what I need to do?

Kind Regards,

Seb

[Log Files]

```
2015-06-22 12:48:53.845 UST Demo[3999:1153643] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x008d0746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00559a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x008d066d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   Foundation                          0x0010edfe -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 139
    4   Foundation                          0x0010ed58 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 68
    5   UST Demo                            0x000768d5 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 213
    6   UIKit                               0x00df3da4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    7   UIKit                               0x00df4095 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00ce5e85 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00ce634c -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
    10  UIKit                               0x00ce6648 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    11  UIKit                               0x0c5c9028 -[UIWindowAccessibility _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 77
    12  UIKit                               0x00cf49b6 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    13  UIKit                               0x00c89ed8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3217
    14  UIKit                               0x00c8d422 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
    15  UIKit                               0x00ca693e __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    16  UIKit                               0x00c8c04a -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x03232c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0323272f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x03244d7c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x007f2050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x007e7963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x007e77bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x007e6a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x007e688b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x00c8ba02 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    26  UIKit                               0x00c8f106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    27  UST Demo                            0x00076dfa main + 138
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c5cac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[Da Maex]

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"354"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lc=uk", path]; // add the '?lc=uk'
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path]; // build URL with string
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

When I've added this code I get this error

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

}

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and examine the values. Or ass NSLog statements for the variables such as `path`, `url `and `request`. Add the log result the the question if you still have problems.

Comment: I've tried doing so, but when testing the app the html doesn't open at all.

I need to add an extension to the index.html but when I do so the file doesn't work. If I remove it the file work but doesn't display anything as it needs an extension to work.

All I need to do is adding index.html?lc=uk to it and thats it.

Isn't there a way to do so?

Comment: Re-read the comment, particularly this part: "Add the log result the the question". We can't guess the results of your code.

Comment: It seems that the log file is to long to paste here :/ 

is there a way for me to post it?

Comment: Add the NSLog statements to the code. Run the app. Copy the log output from the debugger and paste it in the question.

Comment: Done, the log above is with ?lc=uk added to the (ViewController.m) (pathForResources)

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index?lc=uk" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"354"];

Comment: OK, you did not state that you were getting an exception. 1. Add the NSLog statements to the code. Run the app. Copy the log output from the debugger and paste it in the question. 2. To see the actual statement that is causing the error add an exception breakpoint:

From the Mian Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint. Then right-click the breakpoint and add an action: "po $arg1". Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, so don't get angry if I don't understand some stuff. I'm still learning...

Could you be more specific on what you need? As I got lost on (Number 2)

Comment: Read the error message, it is rather clear: "[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter". The path is nil so the statements creating the path are incorrect.

Comment: But this error only happens when I try add ?lc=uk to the (pathForResources) when I remove it the error doesn't happen.. 

So is there a way to add the extension without getting this error, this is all I'm wondering.

Comment: The things I have pointed out fall under debugging. Debugging is a skill all developers ave to learn. You, among other things, have to examine every instruction that could be in the error path. It can be tedious and time consuming, sometimes taking days to find a problem. The best way to reduce debugging time is to throughly understand every line of code one writes.

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right, you need to change the NSString* path like this:

```
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lc=uk", path];
```

But if never tried this for a local Path (`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];`) maybe you should use `[NSURL URLWithString:path];`? Do you have the HTML-File as resource or are you trying to access a remote source?

For a local source the GET-Parameter is eventually even not taken in account, cause there is no PHP or whatever installed as processor for the HTML file.

**edit:**

your Source:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"354"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

new Source:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"354"];
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lc=uk", path]; // add the '?lc=uk'
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path]; // build URL with string
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Da Maex,

I'm sorry but I don't understand where I need to add that Path = [NSString too..

When I look at what I have I don't see it, sorry I'm new to this and just need some help to learn.

Comment: I have the html file in the supporting files folder, all I'm trying to do is add an extension to the index.html file and thats it. But it seems that theres more to it than I thought :(

Comment: I guess, I can't explain my problems well enough to get support on my issue. I'll try figure it out I guess, thanks for trying.

Comment: *NEW*

Hi Da Maex,

I've added the code you gave me but I get this error -

 int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: That is not the error, it's where the error occurred and it's probably a segmentation fault (or something alike) and so it's not showing the right line number. Watch this https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=412 on how-to debug with XCode. Or this youtube Video is also quite good for beginners: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPzSSeJc2oo and then debug your code Line-by-Line and check if the variables are how you want them.

Comment: Thanks, I will watch the video.. But will it help me figure out why its not working?

When running the app it doesn't display anything.

Comment: It will help you understand what is not working, so that you can check your errors and fix them on your own. You have to learn how to debug otherwise you will never produce good code and stop programming eventually.

Comment: I've watched the video it hasn't really explained or showed me how to find the error or issue I'm having. 

Could you give me some suggestion on what I need to do to figure out the problem I'm having.